# How to set directory for images in my website?

Tags: php

My aim is to make a multi-user website which may have between 30 to 3000 users. once one uploads an avatar or an image, How should it handle directory naming?

1- all files in one folder?

2- all files in folders separated by day?

```
/img/upload/2013/05/14/brothers32_5464562.jpg
```

3- all files in folders separated by user name?

```
/img/upload/users/brothers32/5464562.jpg
```

I don't like change my way in mid-way.so, according to your experience which way do you suggest to choose?

Comment: i usually do option 3

Comment: I know from experience it's a real pain to use just one folder when it comes time to to archive.

Comment: since username is probably going to be unique you could probably either save via a folder based on username or all in the same folder but use the username as the avatar name. Separating by day just seems a bit unwieldy as you would have to store when they joined and use it each time.

Comment: Lots of files/directories that share a common parent make a filesystem roll over and die (at about 20K it's so slow it's almost unusable). Also I would suggest setting the directory names in option 2 to the user id, it's less likely to change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agreed with StarCub until I read each user could upload multiple images. Then I'd do this:

Profile picture. All in 1 folder (as StarCub suggested):

```
/img/upload/users/USERID.jpg
```

Uploaded pictures. All in another folder:

```
/img/upload/userimg/2013/PICID.jpg
```

EXCEPT if you expect users to upload many pictures. I'd say 1000-5000 pictures per folder is good, so maybe order them by month depending on what kind of site the page is.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to up 3000 users and each user only has one avatar, I would just put them all in one folder (OPTION 1) and name them use user ID or some sort of unique identifier for that user.

If each user can upload multiple images, then I would use OPTION 3.